# How to combine lists into one with sub list in python

Tags: python, list

Is there a quick and simple way to transform lists (assuming lists with same length) :

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
fruits = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']
```

Into one with sublist with this form :

```
list = [ [1, 'a', 'orange'], 
         [2, 'b', 'apple'], 
         [3, 'c', 'banana'], 
         [4, 'd', 'kiwi'] ]
```

or eventually

```
list = [ {'number': 1, 'letter': 'a', 'fruit': 'oranges'}, 
         {'number': 2, 'letter': 'b', 'fruit': 'apple'}, 
         {'number': 3, 'letter': 'c', 'fruit': 'banana'}, 
         {'number': 4, 'letter': 'd', 'fruit': 'kiwi'} ]
```

Or must I do with multiple loops ?

Comment: For numerical values this is easy with numpy (would be vstack((numbers, letters, fruits)).T ), However numpy yields no suitable solution for arbitrary lists afaik.

Comment: @stewori I hope you mean "no suitable solution _with `numpy`_".

Comment: Sure. I just clarified it. For numerical data the numpy-solution should be atually preferred over the general purpose answers below.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my real code I have numerical values (mostly floats).

Comment: Why my question is a duplicate ? The topic "How to extract column from a multi-dimentional array?" did not answer my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `zip` function.
For first one, just zip them all together and then use map function to tranform inner tuples to list and then make them lists.

Example -

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
fruits = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']
>>> list(map(list, zip(numbers,letters,fruits)))
[[1, 'a', 'orange'], [2, 'b', 'apple'], [3, 'c', 'banana'], [4, 'd', 'kiwi']]
```

Please note for Python 2.x , you do not need the `list(...)` function that is surrounding the `map(..)` function, since it returns list , but in Python 3.x `map(..)` function returns a generator, so if you need list , you need to convert it to list.

For the second one , you can use list comprehension along with zip function, as -

```
>>> list({'number':x,'letter':y,'fruit':z} for x,y,z in zip(numbers,letters,fruits))
[{'number': 1, 'letter': 'a', 'fruit': 'orange'}, {'number': 2, 'letter': 'b', 'fruit': 'apple'}, {'number': 3, 'letter': 'c', 'fruit': 'banana'}, {'number': 4, 'letter': 'd', 'fruit': 'kiwi'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dicts = [dict(zip(('fruit','letter','number'),vals)) for vals in zip(fruits,letters,numbers)]
>>> dicts
[{'fruit': 'orange', 'number': 1, 'letter': 'a'}, {'fruit': 'apple', 'number': 2, 'letter': 'b'}, {'fruit': 'banana', 'number': 3, 'letter': 'c'}, {'fruit': 'kiwi', 'number': 4, 'letter': 'd'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice one for the first:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> c = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']
>>> [[x, y, z] for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)]
[[1, 'a', 'orange'], [2, 'b', 'apple'], [3, 'c', 'banana'], [4, 'd', 'kiwi']]
```